# Redirecting to the login page after fail request validation in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, web-services, validation, laravel-5.1

I am creating Rest Full Api for mobile application, I am validating request it redirects me to the login page with errors.

**Here is my ApiController (I have created for all api):**

```
use App\User as UserModel;
use App\Fb_friend as FbFriendsModel;
use App\Http\Requests\UserRequest;

class ApiController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Create a new movie model instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(UserModel $user, FbFriendsModel $fb_friends){
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->fb_friends = $fb_friends;
    }
    public function createUser (UserRequest $request) {
      // some code here
    }
```

**Route:**

```
Route::post('createUser', ['as' => 'createUser', 'uses' => 'ApiController@createUser']);
```

**UserRequest.php:**

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'fb_id' => 'required|unique:users',
            'username' => 'required|unique:users',
            'email' => 'required|unique:users',
            'image' => 'required',
            'device_id' => 'required',
            'status' => 'required',
        ];
    }
```

**I have override a function Request.php for error formatting:**

```
abstract class Request extends FormRequest
{
    protected function formatErrors(Validator $validator)
    {
        return [$validator->messages()->toJson()];
    }
}
```

**When I try to call service via postman, it returns me error in json format but it also print the login page, I m not getting why?**

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Postman for testing API's, it is not necessary to override the response() in Request class, One can follow the following steps,

1. make return type in authorize() in your custom Request as true,

   ```
   public function authorize()
   {
      //make it true
      return true;
   }
   ```
2. Go to headers section in your Postman and define Accept type,

   ```
   Accept:application/json
   ```
3. Now hit the endpoint of your API and bam..working fine for me.

Comment: The reason for the behavior I suppose is the `response()` method in `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest` where this line `if ($this->expectsJson()) {` checks if the request wants a Json Response otherwise returns a redirects (which I guess go through the web middleware). Hence, the explanation to why adding the `Accept: application/json` to Postman header returns a Json response.

Answer (score 1):

**It has been done by override the `response` method in `app/Http/Requests/Request.php`**

```
public function response(array $errors)  {
        if ($this->ajax() || $this->wantsJson() || Request::isJson()) {
            $newError = [];
            $newError['result'] = false;
            $newError['errors'] = $errors;
            // in the above three lines I have customize my errors array.

            return new JsonResponse($newError, 422);
        }

        return $this->redirector->to($this->getRedirectUrl())
                ->withInput($this->except($this->dontFlash))
                ->withErrors($errors);
    }
```

We also need to use `JsonResponse` class at the top

```
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
```

Source: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-validation-formrequest